# NLTK: how to split based on a given pattern

Tags: python, nltk

if I have this code:

```py
source_text = 'To convert some docs, <g id="1">just click “Add Books” </g>button and then click “<g id="2">Convert”.</g> Set the output format and click <g id="3">“OK”</g>.'

abbreviations = ['e.g', 'i.e']

tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(abbreviations)
tokenizer_dicts = tokenizer.tokenize(source_text)

for tokenized in tokenizer_dicts:
    print(tokenized)
```

this will output:

```
To convert some docs, <g id="1">just click “Add Books” </g>button and then click “<g id="2">Convert”.

</g> Set the output format and click <g id="3">“OK”</g>.
```

whereas the expected result is:

```
To convert some docs, <g id="1">just click “Add Books” </g>button and then click “<g id="2">Convert”.</g>

Set the output format and click <g id="3">“OK”</g>.
```

Notice the `</g>` at the start of the second string is now "moved and appended" to the first string

How do I give it a pattern so it splits like the expected result? or any way around it?